# R LSmeans by group

Tags: r, lsmeans

Is there a way to summarize a dataframe by LSmean values by group? In this example I have 3 different studies, where each one is a RCB design

```
dat = data.frame(expand.grid(study=1:3,
                             trt=1:3, 
                             block=1:4),
                 x=rnorm(36, mean=10, sd=2))
```

Simple means values would be:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(dat, study, trt) %>% summarize(m = mean(x))

> Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
> Groups: study [?]

  study   trt         m
  (int) (int)     (dbl)
1     1     1 10.214407
2     1     2  9.196280
3     1     3 10.129706
4     2     1  8.964452
5     2     2  9.279254
6     2     3  8.584681
7     3     1 10.585306
8     3     2  9.218595
9     3     3  7.961692
```

And LSmeans values for the first study is:

```
library(lsmeans)
fit1 = aov(x ~ factor(trt) + block, data = subset(dat, study==1))
(fit1.rg <- ref.grid(fit1))
lsmeans(fit1.rg, ~trt)

> lsmeans(fit1.rg, ~trt)
 trt   lsmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
   1 10.21441 1.257092  8 7.315547 13.11327
   2  9.19628 1.257092  8 6.297421 12.09514
   3 10.12971 1.257092  8 7.230847 13.02856
```

I don´t really know if it possible to do it all at once or, one by one... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `group_by` followed by `do`, maybe.

Comment: I was just trying something like that... http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/doBy/docs/lsmeans

Comment: Fit the model `x ~ (factor(trt) + block):study`, then use `~ trt|study` as the `lsmeans` spec.

Comment: something like this? `fit = lm(x ~ (factor(trt) + block):study, data=dat); 
summary(fit); 
library(lsmeans); 
lsmeans(fit,~ trt|study)`